# Matlab function huge_add?

Tags: matlab

Can some one please help me solve this question in MATLAB:

> Write function called `huge_add` that adds together two positive integers of any length specified as strings using decimal notation. The single output argument is the result and it is a string as well. The inputs and output must contain digits only; no commas, spaces or any other characters are allowed. If any of these assumptions are violated by the input, the function returns the number `-1`.

The code which I wrote is:

```
function[c]=huge_add(a1,b1)
aaa=length(a1);
bbb=length(b1);
c=0;
if isnumeric(a1) ||isnumeric(b1)
    c=-1;
else if ~isnumeric(a1) ||~isnumeric(b1)
        for i=1:aaa
            if a1(i)~='1'&& a1(i)~='2'&&a1(i)~='3'&&a1(i)~='4'&&a1(i)~='5'&&a1(i)~='6'&&a1(i)~='7'&&a1(i)~='8'&&a1(i)~='9'&&a1(i)~='0'
               c=-1;
            end
        end
        for i=1:bbb
            if  b1(i)~='1'&&b1(i)~='2'&&b1(i)~='3'&&b1(i)~='4'&&b1(i)~='5'&&b1(i)~='6'&&b1(i)~='7'&&b1(i)~='8'&&b1(i)~='9'&&b1(i)~='0'
                c=-1;
            end
        end
    end
a=a1;
b=b1;
aa=length(a);
bb=length(b);
    as=(str2num(a));
    bs=(str2num(b));
    af=fliplr(a);
    bf=fliplr(b);
    if c~=-1
        if aa<bb
            for ii=1:aa
                x(ii)=af(ii);
                y(ii)=bf(ii);
                z(ii)=str2num(x(ii))+str2num(y(ii));
                zz{ii}=num2str(z(ii));
            end
    cl=fliplr(z);
    rem=(b(1):b(bb-aa));
    ca=[rem,cl(1):cl(end)];
    else if aa>bb
            for ii=1:bb
                x(ii)=af(ii);
                y(ii)=bf(ii);
                z(ii)=str2num(x(ii))+str2num(y(ii));
                zz(ii)=num2str(z(ii))
            end
    cl=fliplr(z);
    rem=(a(1):a(aa-bb));
    ca=[rem,cl(1):cl(end)];
        else
            for ii=1:aa
                x(ii)=af(ii);
                y(ii)=bf(ii);
                z(ii)=str2num(x(ii))+str2num(y(ii));
                zz(ii)=num2str(z(ii));
            end
      cl=fliplr(z);
      rem=[];
      ca=[rem,cl(1):cl(end)];
        end
        end
      d=str2num([rem,fliplr(zz)])
      %d=([rem,fliplr(zz)])
      c=num2str(d);
      end 
end
end
```

And the error I get is

```
Feedback: Your function performed correctly for argument(s) '1', '1'
Feedback: Your function performed correctly for argument(s) '10', '22'
Feedback: Your function performed correctly for argument(s) '1234', '1'
Feedback: Your function performed correctly for argument(s) '0', '0'
Feedback: Your function performed correctly for argument(s) '12', '-2'
Feedback: Your function performed correctly for argument(s) '99.99', '0'
Feedback: Your function performed correctly for argument(s) '1,234', '1'
Feedback: Your function performed correctly for argument(s) 12, 34
Feedback: Your function performed correctly for argument(s) [1 2 3], '1'
Feedback: Your function performed correctly for argument(s) '2', [50 51 52]
Feedback: Your program made an error for argument(s) '612455618766556780', '6285757'

Your solution is _not_ correct.
```

PLEASE HELP.....

Comment: I don't understand why this needs to be 65 lines of loops. Can you not use  [`+`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plus.html) and [`sprintf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html)?

Comment: Thank you for your kind help. I am not really sure how to incorporate them in the code. New to programming and still trying to understand it better and better. Could you guide me about it please

Comment: I have linked the documentation which is filled with examples.

Comment: Thank you really appreciate it.. It might be a while before I can decode it but thank you..!!

Answer (score -2):

This function won't work for any `a1 ='abcd', b1 = 'ABCD'` when `c+C>=10` (or any other entry)
you need to carry the 1 properly. after the line `z(ii)=str2num(x(ii))+str2num(y(ii));`
you should check if `z(ii)>10` and if it does then carry the 1 forward.

By the way, this is the reason only the last example didn't work.

Comment: Hi Idekel, Thank you could you elaborate a little or tweak that part of the code...I am new to programming so sometimes find it hard to follow the kind helps...!! Thank you for your kind help..!!

Comment: function n=huge_add(n1,n2)
if isnumeric(n1) && isnumeric(n2);
n=-1;
else
bn1=n1; bn2=n2; n1=double(str2num(n1)); n2=double(str2num(n2));
en1=num2str(n1); en2=num2str(n2);
if strcmp(en1,bn1) && strcmp(en2,bn2)
    if n1<0 && n2<0
       n=-1;
    else
        if ~(n1-round(n1)) && ~(n1-round(n1))
           n=num2str(n1+n2);
        else
            n=-1;
        end
    end
else
n=-1;
end
end

Comment: Feedback: Your function performed correctly for argument(s) '1', '1'
Feedback: Your function performed correctly for argument(s) '10', '22'
Feedback: Your function performed correctly for argument(s) '1234', '1'
Feedback: Your function performed correctly for argument(s) '0', '0'
Feedback: Your function made an error for argument(s) '12', '-2'

    Your solution is _not_ correct.

Comment: Idekel, I tried modifying the function as per your kind input, I am still getting the same error...any help please..!!